# How to render a value from an .rb file into an .erb file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, frontend

I don't have much experience with Ruby all I wan't to do is render a value that I declare in an .rb file in an .erb file.

In my .rb file I have this:

```
def abc()
  begin
     "aaaaa"
  end
end
```

In my .erb file I have this:

```
Hello <% abc %>
```

When I run the app I only see:

> Hello

But I expect to see:

> Hello aaaa

Anybody can give me a hand, I don't really know ruby at all. Also I have no idea if this is ruby or ruby on rails so sorry if the tag below is wrong.

Comment: In Ruby it's conventional to omit empty argument lists, so `abc()` should be `abc` both when defined and when called. Additionally, `begin` / `end` serve no purpose inside that method.

Comment: If this is within Rails, where does that `abc` method get defined? If it's within a controller you'll need to flag it as a `helper_method`. If it's within a helper you may need to import it into the controller first.

Comment: @tadman I am not sure I am a bit confused. Maybe there is no rails in here. How can i know if this is rails? I don't thing it's Rails I can't find the word rails anywhere in the project.

Comment: I'm just asking because you tagged this as Rails, but if it's just a regular Ruby project then you'll need to add the part where you call the `ERB` method to render things.

Comment: @tadman I am trying this now `Hello <% helper_method abc %>` but it's throwing me an error saying: `undefined method `helper_method' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x00007fe3c6390268>`

Comment: Also I tried adding `helper_method :abc` in the .rb file but that also tells me `undefined method `helper_method' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x00007fe3c6390268>`

Comment: If this is Sinatra then `helper_method` doesn't apply, as that's for Rails.

Answer (score 3):

In Sinatra, register your method as a helper in .rb file:

```
helpers do 
  def abc
    "aaaaa"
  end 
end
```

Omit parentheses if your methods don't need arguments. Also, `begin/end` block isn't necessary here. 
You can call your helper in .erb template:

`<%= abc %>`

Don't forget `=` in the opening tag.

http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html section 'Helpers'.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you want to achieve. But If you just want some text in your erb you can do something like this:

```
erb :myerb, locals: {text: "aaaaa", saved: false}
```

myerb.erb

```
<% if saved %>
  Hello <%= text %>
<% endif %>
```

This would also work for functions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to be aware that a defined method inherently includes the functionality of a begin/end block so you don´t need to put them again. Assuming you are using sinatra, here is what I think you need:

my.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

def abc
  "aaaa"
end

get '/' do
  erb :my, locals: {variable: abc}
end
```

my.erb

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
       Hello <%= variable %>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run ruby my.rb and then open http://localhost:4567/